# React dropdown fetch from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropdown, fetch-api, react-select

I want to build "React Dropdown", which will give me options to select user while I type first letters of his name.

Users data is coming from my backend API in JSON format.

```json
// http://localhost:5000/users
{
  "users": [
    {
      "company_id": 1,
      "name": "Sally Mae"
    },
    {
      "company_id": 2,
      "name": "Johnathan Ives"
    },
    {
      "company_id": 3,
      "name": "John Smith"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's my fetch part, but I can't fetch, but my server is running, this is the code

```js
fetchData = (inputValue, callback) => {
    if (!inputValue) {
      callback([]);
    } else {
        setTimeout(() => {
  fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/users/" + inputValue, {
    method: "GET",
  })
  .then((resp) => {
    console.log(resp);
    return resp.json()
  }) 
  .then((data) => {
     const tempArray = [];
     data.forEach((users) => {
      console.log(tempArray);
      tempArray.push({ label: `${users.name}`, value: `${users.name}`});
      console.log(tempArray);
     });
     callback(tempArray);            
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error, "catch the hoop")
  });
});
}
}
```

Appreciate any help !

Comment: Hey there! Please take a look at the Help Center - especially the topic [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) The question currently needs some additional details, for example, what errors are you getting? What should be happening and what is happening instead? What have you tried? Please  use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64248644/edit) button below your question to add details to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you misunderstand here is that `callback`, of your `loadOptions` prop, is where you wrap your retrieval method.

```js
const getData = (inputValue) =>
  fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/users/' + inputValue, {
    method: 'GET',
  })
    .then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then((data) =>
      data.map((user) => ({ label: user.name, value: user.name }))
    )
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error, 'catch the hoop');
    });

const fetchData = (inputValue, callback) => {
  if (!inputValue) {
    callback(Promise.resolve([]));
  } else {
    callback(getData(inputValue));
  }
};
```